# How can I create a playlist and add songs to it in cmus?

Tags: cmus

Question's in the title, really. Cmus documentation is pretty light on how to create new play lists, add songs to them, and then play them. I'd like to know step-by-step how to do that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

And I just figured it out.

1. `:pl-create my-playlist`
2. `3` to navigate to the playlists window
3. Highlight the new playlist and press <kbd>space</kbd> to mark it.
4. Add songs using either of the following:

   - `:add -p ~/Music/artist/` to add songs from that directory to the marked playlist
   - Go to the "Sorted library view" by pressing <kbd>2</kbd>
     -> find artist / song / directory / etc. by searching with `/`
     -> select the desired songs with <kbd>space</kbd>
     -> press <kbd>y</kbd> to "*[copy tracks to the marked playlist](https://github.com/cmus/cmus/blob/1849b0ae254e1d37104495639a51cb0bb4246d43/Doc/cmus.txt#L144)*"

> TIP: If you need an online version of the CMUS man page, go to the [CMUS documentation page](https://cmus.github.io/#documentation). While the versions linked there are harder on the eyes, they are still better than the other hopelessly out of date ones.

Comment: You can also `cd` into `.config/cmus/playlists` and then `touch` files. Then follow the `:add -p...` part.

Comment: Great, never seen the option (:pl-create) before. Helped me out with being able to create playlists. PS once you have created a playlist be sure to save it with :save -p nameoflist

Comment: @DeepDeadpool Hope you don't mind the edit - I would have just copied your answer into a new one and added the few lines in the end.

Comment: No it's a good edit. Thanks.