# How can I start a playlist from the command line in cmus?

Tags: bash, cmus

I would like to start playing a play list from cmus with a command line. This is to create a bash alias that would start playing a specific playlist. I tried

```
cmus pl-import playlist_name
```

But it doesn't import the playlist.

This question [How can I create a playlist and add songs to it in cmus?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/593727/how-can-i-create-a-playlist-and-add-songs-to-it-in-cmus) explains how to create a playlist and add songs to it from within cmus.